# Select multiple tables like a partial dump

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

This is more of a general question: I'm building an REST API where an Android can connect to and here is my problem:
How would I tackle a **"partial" dump** from a database when I exclude some tables? Would I need a big sql query?
I can't export the whole database. It should function as a (unidirectional) Server->Client database synchronization to a Android SQLite database. Maybe this is the wrong approach, if so, what would be the better way?

[image: database]

I'd need an output like this:

```
$db = Array
 (
  [assetsTable] => Array
     (
     [row1] => Array
        (      
        [AssetID] => 1,
        [LocationID] => '1',
        ...
        )
     [row2] => Array
        (...)
  [locationTable] => Array
      (
       [row1] => Array
         (
         [LocationID] => 1
   (...)
```

Comment: I think get core points in your database representing "major" entities, add a "date changed" column in each, then get reflected queries from other tables regarding IDs of recently changed entities. Store the last synch somewhere, of course, to have a standpoint and not miss any records.